# Python Shopify Scraper not scraping all collections

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm using this scraper to scraper Shopify stores:

https://github.com/helloiamelliot/shopify-python-scraping-tool/blob/master/shopify.py

When I run `python shopify.py [url]` some collections are scraped but not all

I'll check the collections with `python shopify.py --list-collections [URL]` and then search by a specific collection and the scraper will scrape products that weren't in the original query.

For example:
If I run `python shopify.py -c wipes https://shop.superbodycare.com/` 2 product are scraped.

However, when I run:

```
python shopify.py https://shop.superbodycare.com/
```

the 2 products from the original query aren't scraped.

Any idea why? I want every product to be scraped without querying each collection.